# Как фильтровать передаваемые параметры php

Tags: php, ajax, xss, sql-injection

Передаю параметры ajax на php обработчик и проверяю с помощью функции [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-escape-string.php) может ли это защитить от инъекций и ХSS?

```
$absnum = mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']);
```

Comment: Что у вас в `$_POST['id']` ожидается?

Comment: А [доки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-escape-string.php) читали? `This function was deprecated in PHP 4.3.0` и далее `Функция экранирует unescaped_string таким образом, после чего её можно безопасно использовать в mysql_query(). Данная функция устарела.

Функция идентична mysql_real_escape_string(), исключая тот факт, что mysql_real_escape_string() принимает параметром ещё и идентификатор соединения и экранирует строку с учетом текущей кодировки. mysql_escape_string() не делает этого и результат работы не зависит от кодировки, в который вы работаете с БД.`

Comment: Кстати, `mysql_real_escape_string` тоже устарело

Comment: @modelfak, ответьте на вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Visman ожидается строка вобще произвольная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как фильтровать передаваемые параметры php

Никак. Никакая фильтрация передаваемым в РНР параметрам не требуется.

> может ли это защитить от инъекций и ХSS?

Нет.

Эта функция ни малейшего отношения ни к одной, ни к другой уязвимости не имеет.

Чтобы защититься от "инъекций", надо использовать PDO, передавая переменные в запрос через плейсхолдеры.

Чтобы защититься от XSS, надо выводить пользовательские данные, обработав их функцией `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Эта функция имеет отношение к sql-инъекциям. В остальном всё верно.

Answer (score -2):

Да, функция mysql_escape_string() сделана чтобы решать проблему SQL-injection. Но только рекомендуется заменить её на более новую `mysql_real_escape_string()`, а еще рекомендуется отказаться от устаревшего расширения mysql в пользу mysqli или PDO.

Если идти по пути наименьших телодвижений, можно перейти на процедурный вариант mysqli. Достаточно поиском-с-заменой пройтись по текстам и переделать mysql_* на mysqli_* и потом буквально чуточку обработать чтобы где надо упоминался пропущенный параметр $link. В таком случае, защитой будет `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

От внедрения скриптов (XSS) есть другое лекарство: функции `htmlspecialchars()` или `htmlentities()`. Они превращают знаки "<" и ">" в коды &lt; и &gt; и поэтому враг не сможет ввести такой комментарий, который при выводе на страницу создал бы тег <script> Популярные шаблонизаторы по умолчанию оборачивают весь вывод в одну из этих функций.

Читать:

- http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php
- http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php (см. Предостережение)
- https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS